# does not show the right result when use is_dir() in php

Tags: php

test4.php

```
<?php
var_dump(is_dir("../test4.php"));
?>
```

I run `http://localhost/oop/test4.php`, it shows: `boolean false`

Question:

`../test4.php` means `oop` folder, right? why the result is `false`, not `true`? I am using WAMP on win7 local computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test4.php` is not a directory, it's a file.  If you want the directory up from the current one, just use `../`.